# How to make customize label like balloon tooltip in windows Form C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

Background: I am making desktop C# Windows Form Application.I want to display permanently balloon ToolTip as you can see in the image.

[This is what I want to Achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXwAX.png).

**Tried**: I have tried custom tooltip.My code is below,

```
ToolTip customToolTip = new ToolTip();
        customToolTip.ToolTipTitle = "Button Tooltip";
        customToolTip.UseFading = true;
        customToolTip.UseAnimation = true;
        customToolTip.IsBalloon = true;
        customToolTip.Active = true;
        customToolTip.ShowAlways = true;
        customToolTip.ShowAlways = true;
```

**Problem with the solutions**: The problem is I want to show permanently without mouse hover and ToolTip only comes when mouse hover that control and After some time it disappears. I have read on StackOverflow that by default its in the tooltip characteristics that disappears after some time and he said he you want to show permanently, go for the label.
I want to make balloon type tooltip and want to display with out mouse hover that displays permanently?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `NotifyIcon`. Eg:

**Method 1:**

```
private void ShowBalloonTip(int min)
{
   NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
   notifyIcon.Visible = true;
   notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
   notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Enter the text to be shown";
   notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Enter the Title";
   notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(min * 60 * 1000); // You can set your time value here
}
```

**This will be shown(without mouse hover)** as long as the mentioned time. If mouse is hovered above it, it will get automatically dismissed.

**NOTE** : This will get *dismissed* after a certain time(the time you passed as `min`) . So pass a value like for an hour or so. This would keep it alive thus long!

If somehow NotifyIcon is not showing up, use

```
notifyIcon.Icon = SystemIcons.Application;
```

**Method 2:**

Alternatively try this

```
var notify = new NotifyIcon();
notify.Visible = true;
notify.Icon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information;
notify.ShowBalloonTip(3000, "Title", "TextBody", ToolTipIcon.Info)
//3000 is in milliseconds
```

Comment: Did you assign an `Icon` to it? If the above mentioned way doesn't work. replace the `notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon` with `notifyIcon.Icon = SystemIcons.Application;`

Comment: I've updated my answer, Check **Method 2**. Copy the same code and check first. Replace `3000`, `Title` , `TextBody` as per your preference. Don't set the time to 3 or 4 because **ShowBalloonTip** takes **milliseconds** as _parameter_. So _convert_ your time duration to milliseconds

Comment: This is working but It is showing in the notification area and I want to display in WindowsForm around the control? How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is the best you can achieve now. Showing notification bubbles on the app quick-start icon like you have shown in the picture is not possible! I'm sorry about that. But if my solution would suffice your need, you can accept it by clicking the tick on the left :)

Comment: Please tell me one last thing, That will solve my problem, Consider the scenario, I have an Image on Computer and Want to achieve what I have shown you in the picture than what should I do? your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Pardon me, but I didn't get what you are asking properly. If I'm not wrong,  you have a picture on your computer, and you want to achieve _something_ as shown in the picture. Do you want to include a picture in the notification bubble?

Comment: Like User Clicked on Google Chrome and I saved the picture and Now I want to display on Google Chrome "Left Click on Google Chrome" as You can see in the picture. I dont know how to display this.

Comment: How can I add caption like Ballooon type on Image in C# ? how can I add image in my balloon captions ?

Comment: Unfortunately NotifyIcon does not support that. It **Won't** let you add a **Image** or use a **Custom Icon** . Its a sealed class and you can't do anything about it!

Comment: What else can I try ? just give an idea

Comment: @mohsin Check [this](https://github.com/Tulpep/Notification-Popup-Window). I suppose it has most of the things that you require.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically trigger a ToolTip, use the [ToolTip.Show Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show(v=vs.110).aspx). Example code:

```
  var tooltip = new ToolTip();
  tooltip.ToolTipTitle = "Tooltip title";
  tooltip.IsBalloon = true;
  tooltip.Show("tooltip content", Target);
```

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, ToolTip only comes when mouse hovers on the control and I dont want it. I want to show permanently without mouse hovering.

Comment: I want to achieve same functionality with Label and want balloon display in Label /

Comment: @mohsin have you tried using `BalloonTip` / `NotifyIcon` instead of `ToolTip`

Comment: @mohsin No, please read my answer again. The Show() call triggers the ToolTip *without requiring a mouse hover*.

Comment: @mohsin `NotifyIcon` has `notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip();`. You can enter the timevalue in it, thus rendering it show for that long, Even without mouse hover it will be shown

Comment: @Nobody, Does BalloonTip/NotifyIcon have the properties of permanently show and without the mouse hover and does not disappear after some time? I have not tried it.

Comment: @Paul-Jan ok. But it disappears after some time, I don't want that? How to resolve this ?

Comment: @Nobody I am trying and will tell you the results.

Comment: @mohsin See my answer